# How to watch on descendant child nodes in Python using kazoo?

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, watch, kazoo

I recently started working with `Python for Zookeeper`. I am using `kazoo` library for Zookeeper.

I have a very simple use case using [kazoo](http://kazoo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic_usage.html#watchers) for Zookeeper. I have a root node which is - `/root`. Now I need to keep a watch on the root node `/root` and if the new node which gets added to root node `/root` is `/root/testing` then I will only keep a watch on the `/root/testing` node. I don't want to keep a watch on any other node apart from the `testing` node. And then if any new children get added up to the `/root/testing` node, then I will keep a watch on them as well.

Let's say the child below that gets added up -

```
`/root/testing/test1`
```

Then I will keep a watch on `test1` node as well.

Is this possible to do using Kazoo in Zookeeper? I am only able to keep a watch on one Zookeeper node (`/root`) with the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

from kazoo.client import KazooClient

zk = KazooClient(hosts='127.0.0.1:2181')
zk.start()

########################################
@zk.ChildrenWatch("/root/testing")
def watch_children(children):
   print(children)

########################################

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Can anyone help me with this in making multiple watches on the child node?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
import time
from kazoo.client import KazooClient

zk = KazooClient(hosts='127.0.0.1:2181')
zk.start()

children = zk.get_children("/root/",)
if "/testing" in children:
    children_testing = zk.get_children("/root/testing/")
        if children_testing != []: 
            @zk.ChildrenWatch("/root/testing")
            def watch_children(children):
                print(children)
        else:
            @zk.ChildrenWatch("/root/")
            def watch_children(children):
                print(children)
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to watch over multiple nodes, rather than one, you could use multiple threads (basically it runs different code simultaneously on different "threads"). Python has a threading module for doing simultaneous actions, which may be exactly what you want. Here is an example of code with threads implemented.

```
import threading

def watch_node(node):
    #implement your node watching script here

def watch_in_background(node):
    watcher = threading.Thread(target=watch_node,args=(node))   #initializes a thread that can run the watch_node function in the background, passing the node argument to it
    watcher.start()                                             #tells the thread to start running
    return watcher                                              #returns the thread object just in case you want to use it for something

watch_in_background(<node>)                                     #so this code will now watch the node in the background, allowing you to do other things, like watch multiple nodes
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but my question is specifically related to kazoo library for zookeeper, I am not able to understand how to put a watches on parent child, and then its child as well.

Comment: The script that watches the nodes, using Kazoo, can be executed many times at once using threading. The use of Kazoo should not influence threading.